# React Swiper Navigation not working. How to work it?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

Here's my code below. Navigation arrows are not appering.

```
import {Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y} from 'swiper';
import {Swiper, SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react'

import 'swiper/css'
import 'swiper/css/navigation'

 <Swiper 
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]}
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={5}
        Navigation={true}
        onSlideChange={()=> console.log('slide change')}
        onSwiper={(swiper)=> console.log(swiper)}
        >
            <SwiperSlide>Slide1</SwiperSlide>
 </Swiper>
```

Warning: React does not recognize the `Navigation` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `navigation` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.